# Does the Rick & Morty comic spoil the published adventure?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, the-lost-dungeon-of-rickedness

Does reading the graphic novel series [*Rick and Morty vs. Dungeons & Dragons*](https://www.idwpublishing.com/product/rick-and-morty-vs-dungeons-dragons-1/) spoil the published D&D 5e adventure [*Dungeons & Dragons vs. Rick and Morty*](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/dungeons-dragons-vs-rick-and-morty)? I'm in the middle of playing the D&D adventure as a player, but I am thinking of reading the graphic novel series before finishing the adventure and I don't want to ruin the game for our group.

In [this interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mMuI-ojTBAc), Kate Welch says that they are the same characters:

> So, in this adventure you can play the characters played by the Smith family in the comic book, which are Morty, Summer, Beth, Jerry and a fifth mystery character.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After getting through all 4 comic books, I can say without a doubt there are no spoilers for the one-shot.